# Shortcode arguments to another shortcode

Tags: shortcode, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning about shortcodes. I've made 2 shortcodes that makes an accordion with bootstrap. One shortode (accordionGroup) creates the body that contains one or more shortcodes to make the items and it's content (accordionItem).

Now I need to create 2 different accordion. The problem is: I need a different id for each accordion and parse it to each item from that accordion. That is to make the accordion animation.

Here is the code

```
//This is the accordion container
function accordionGroup( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id_container' => '',
), $atts));
    return "<div class='panel-group' id=".$id_container." role='tablist' aria-multiselectable='true'>".do_shortcode($content)."</div>";
}
add_shortcode( 'accordion-group', 'accordionGroup');

//This is the accordion item. It's need a reference from the accordion ID
function accordionItem( $atts, $content = null)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'titulo' => '',
    'id' => '',
), $atts));

    return "
        <div class='panel panel-default'>
            <div class='panel-heading' role='tab' id=".$id.">
                <h4 class='panel-title'>
                    <a class='collapsed' role='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#the-reference-goes-here' href='#".$id."-collapse' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls=".$id."-collapse'>".$titulo."</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id='".$id."-collapse' class='panel-collapse collapse' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby=".$id.">
                <div class='panel-body'>".$content."</div>
            </div>
        </div>";
}
add_shortcode( 'accordion-item', 'accordionItem');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the variable via a `global` but it would be neater to trap it in a static variable:

```
function track_acc_id($new_id = false) {
  static $id;
  if (!empty($new_id)) {
    $id = $new_id;
  }
  return $id;
}

//This is the accordion container
function accordionGroup( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id_container' => '',
), $atts));

    track_acc_id($id_container);

    return "<div class='panel-group' id=".$id_container." role='tablist' aria-multiselectable='true'>".do_shortcode($content)."</div>";
}
add_shortcode( 'accordion-group', 'accordionGroup');

//This is the accordion item. It's need a reference from the accordion ID
function accordionItem( $atts, $content = null)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'titulo' => '',
    'id' => '',
), $atts));

    $id = track_acc_id();

    return "
        <div class='panel panel-default'>
            <div class='panel-heading' role='tab' id=".$id.">
                <h4 class='panel-title'>
                    <a class='collapsed' role='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#the-reference-goes-here' href='#".$id."-collapse' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls=".$id."-collapse'>".$titulo."</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id='".$id."-collapse' class='panel-collapse collapse' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby=".$id.">
                <div class='panel-body'>".$content."</div>
            </div>
        </div>";
}
add_shortcode( 'accordion-item', 'accordionItem');

echo do_shortcode('[accordion-group id_container="d00d"]');
echo do_shortcode('[accordion-item]');
```

Or the whole thing into a class.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you remove `extract()`. ;-)

Comment: My answer would be more useful if I a did a number of things to clean up that code, or refactor completely, but I have limited time.

Comment: No problem, understood :-)

Comment: I'm am wondering if it is even too complex in principle and the same results can be achieved with much less markup.

Answer (score 0):

I have just read your code and is this correct

```
$id_container
```

instead

```
$atts['id_container']
```

And may be this code error for you. Can you check once this?

Comment: The 'data-toggle' inside the accordionItem function needs to point to the accordion ID that contain it. All I need is a way to get the ID from accordionGroup function and pass it into accordionItem.

For example, if the accordion has id="animation" (accordionGroup), the items from that accordion (accordionItem) must have data-toogle="#animation". If another accordion has id="videogames", the items from that accordion must have datat-toggle="#videogames", and so on.